# Writing a function to adapt for two different cases?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express

Maybe I am not thinking hard enough but lets say I have code that is 99% similar what would be the most minimal way of building a function for it?

```
// this is just an express route, not the function I am building
// doPay() is the function I am trying to build properly
function(req,res) {

  if(req.user) {

    // I can use req.user.id in my function
    doPay(req,res);

  } else {

    passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {

      // instead of req.user.id I would just need user.id
      doPay();

    });

  }

}
```

**doPay()**

```
// My doPay() function, above I need to pass either req.user.id or user.id
// based on the boolean, so how do I adjust this to adapt to that?
gateway.customer.find(req.user.id, function(err, customer) {

  //do payment stuff for an existing user, if the user is new I need to use
  //user.id above

});
```

Comment: Just give `doPay` a parameter for the `id`?

Comment: I actually do think it is that simple, isnt it. I just woke up and need more coffee..

Comment: I haven't used passport, so I don't know how it actually works, but normally you would have something like: `.get( authModule(options), function(req, res) {  doPay(req.user) });`  and the `authModule` would take care about if the user is auth and has the correct right, or if a login screen or error page needs to be shown.

Comment: Yeah thats using it as a middleware, correct. I am not doing it that way due to the nature of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You should make you signature of the function clear. As you sometimes don't have `req` only passing `user` to  `doPay` then this function either does not need  `req` at all, so you should always pass only `user` to it or you have and a  check if `req` exists or not, then you most likely mixing some routing parts with internal logic and you should think over dividing your `doPay` in two different functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer t.niese, I am not 100% sure what you mean, but I do need the `req` object for both methods, because the req gathers mostly the same information, the only thing that changes is when the user has not been authenticated and then becomes authenticated gets an ID, whereas an existing user object is stored in the `req`.

Comment: Ok, so  after the `passport.authenticate` the `user` of the callback actually belongs to the request. So what is the reason why you don't do **a)** a `doPay(req, res,  req.user);`  for the first case and a `doPay(req, res, user);`  for the second. Or **b)**  a  `req.user = user;` in the second case before calling `doPay(req,res);`? I actually don't see a reason why the `doPay` function needs to do this kind of decision, as it is more obvious at the place where you do the call.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean t.niese thanks thats a good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two alternate designs.

You could make the function take 3 parameters

```
function doPay(req, res, user)
```

and then test in that function to select what is available

```
var userId;
if (req && req.user && req.user.id) userId = req.user.id;
if (!userId && user && user.id) userId = user.id;
if (!userId) throw "error...";
```

or you could choose to make the 3rd parameter the userId to use

```
 function doPay(req,res,userId)
```

and put the userId source logic in the routing code instead of the doPay code.  The doPay would just use the userId it was told to use.  I think this design is what @Bergi was suggesting in the first comment.

Comment: Yeah thats basically what I did. WIll check this when I can

Comment: In the 2nd case, the question posted doesn't show any parameters being passed.  Here you can call it as `doPay(null, res, user)`

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I still need the `req` for other information. The only reason I dont use req.user.id is because when the user is authenticated the user object hasnt been created and does get created inside the authenticate method.

Comment: Well, if `req.user` is undefined you can still pass req and the code above would select `user.id` or throw the error.  Anyway, what you are trying to do sounds like it could be solved along these lines  If you are still stuck later, maybe you can get a better answer at that point as there will be more info about the requirements.

Comment: Oh okay thanks Paul. It's all working, I just want to keep from repeating code so I wouldn't confuse myself, wouldn't want that to happen dealing with payments. Thanks, have a good day!!